# What does it take to fulfill my commitment and get the beta badge?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges

I thought by answering/asking so many questions I could fulfill my commitment and get the beta badge.  I have 11 questions/answers with 10 of them having votes.  Other's have received the beta badge with fewer questions/answers?  What am I missing?  I don't see any reference anywhere to what the requirements are for fulfilling my commitment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It I understand the beta badge it's only given to those who were around when gis was in private beta phase, we are currently in public beta. there is more info about the phases on [area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425/geographic-information-systems).

Comment: Hmm, that's confusing.  I committed before the beta started and logged into gis.stackexchange as soon as the sysmte allowed me which was about a week after the beta started.  Does that mean I'm not able to fulfill my commitment?

Comment: @Jay-Askren According to the log on Area51 it seems like the private beta started exactly on the same time as the public beta. Maybe the private beta phase was skipped?

Comment: There are 49 people with Beta badges.

Comment: I agree with you, that's strange.

Comment: It is curious. I started with the project before the beta started. My area51 profile says my commitment is fulfilled, yet I don't have the beta badge. Oh hang on, is it because there isn't a "beta" badge? None listed at http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges at any rate.

Comment: The beta badge is listed on http://gis.stackexchange.com however.

Comment: It looks like you might be right.  I finally got an email saying my commitment is fulfilled.  I'm not sure how one gets in the private beta vs public beta, but at least the commitment is fulfilled now.

Comment: You need to be "active" in the beta.

Comment: Isn't asking/answering questions the same as being active?

Answer (score 5):

commitment and beta badge are two different concepts.

1. beta badge requires a certain level of activity during the *private* beta.
2. commitment is measured for the duration of the public and private beta -- as long as you have a reasonable amount of questions/answers, you should get it. see http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq for details